# How to multiply two doubles into double in Android?

Tags: android

I want to multiply two values that are double and show its result. Here c1= 10.0 and dis or condition1=1.82 and inc=4.00 and inac== 15.00. I have checked every variable in toast. Every variable is giving value. I think the problem lies in multiplying method.

```js
 db=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("ServiceConsumers").child("distance");
        db.child(currentUser).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                dis=dataSnapshot.child("distance").getValue().toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "dis" + dis,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                conditn1=Double.valueOf(dis);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "conditn1" +conditn1,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        if (conditn1 >= c1){
            double total= conditn1 * inac;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "pay" + total, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            paymnt.setText(String.valueOf(total));
        } else {
            if (conditn1 <= c1){
            double mult=conditn1*inc;
                //String tot=String.valueOf(conditn1 * inc);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "payi = " + mult, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                paymnt.setText(String.valueOf(mult));

            }
        }

        rate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RateProvider.class);
                intent.putExtra("prvdrName", value3);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


    }
```

Comment: But what is the problem?

Comment: where are you adding and not getting result. Please mark that in code

Comment: the values are retrivng from firebase.. i am multiplying it simply. the result gives 0.0

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your information, almost every function(s) of Firebase are Async Functions. 
So you should do your calculation inside **onDataChange** method.

So your code will be

```
db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("ServiceConsumers").child("distance");
db.child(currentUser).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
 @Override
 public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

  dis = dataSnapshot.child("distance").getValue().toString();
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "dis" + dis, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


  conditn1 = Double.valueOf(dis);
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "conditn1" + conditn1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

  if (conditn1 >= c1) {
   double total = conditn1 * inac;
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "pay" + total, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   paymnt.setText(String.valueOf(total));
  } else {
   if (conditn1 <= c1) {
    double mult = conditn1 * inc;
    //String tot=String.valueOf(conditn1 * inc);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "payi = " + mult, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    paymnt.setText(String.valueOf(mult));

   }
  }
 }

 @Override
 public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

 }
});
```